# Use mongodb aggregation framework to group by length of array

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "id0",
    "name": "...",
    "saved_things": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ]
}
{
    "_id": "id1",
    "name": "...",
    "saved_things": [
        { ... },
    ]
}
{
    "_id": "id2",
    "name": "...",
    "saved_things": [
        { ... },
    ]
}
```

etc...

I want to use mongodb's aggregation framework in order to come up with a histogram result that tells how many users have a certain count of the `saved_things`. For example, for the dataset above it could return something like:

```js
{ "_id": 1, "count": 2 },
{ "_id": 3, "count": 1 }
```

I've tried various combinations of aggregate functions like the one below, but none have worked out correctly. (I get the feeling that I'm going about this terribly wrong.)

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$saved_things" },
    { $group: "$_id", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $group: "$count", number: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { number: -1 } }
], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Is this possible with Mongo's aggregate framework or would I be better off with a map reduce function?

Comment: What you mean with _how many users have a certain count of the saved_things subcollectin_ ? Given a `saved_thing`, you want to know which users have the `saved_things` and how much? Is that?

Comment: Hmm my wording seems to be confusing, sorry about that! I think the example output best describes what I'm looking for, but I'll try to describe it again.

I'd like to get the number of objects in `saved_things` for each user in the collection and aggregate the frequency of that count. It's for generating a histogram of number of users' `saved_things` (if that makes sense).

Let me know if that's still confusing in any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, got it! Here we go. The aggregation pipeline is basically that:

```
{
    $unwind: "$saved_things"
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        size: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$size",
        frequency: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        size: "$_id",
        frequency: 1,
        _id: 0
    }
}
```

Unwind `saved_things` array, then group by document `_id` and count it, thus we can achieve the array size. Now is easy, group by `size` and count the frequency. Use project to rename `_id` field to `size`.

Comment: Looks like it's really close. I'm getting this as the output: https://gist.github.com/stevenleeg/2b1a2ee9c5400f5f3089

Comment: Just kidding! I was echoing out `results` rather than `result` which caused the problem. The only thing I see that isn't quite working is that there is no data for frequency 0. Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: i dont believe this aggregation will include a frequency value for documents with a zero length array. Was scratching my head for a minute as to why my frequency totals didnt match my particular collection count.

Answer (score 3):

you can use $size key
Example

```
query :

[{ 
   $group: {
     _id:{$size:'$saved_things'},
     total: { $sum: 1 },
   }
}]

output:
[{ _id: 4, total: 2 }]
```