# Mongoid: group by array size, and count each group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection whose documents each has an array.
I'd like to write a query to analyze the distribution of the size of this array.

Result I'm expecting is an array of hashes {size_of_array => count_of_document}

```
[
  {0 => 101},
  {1 => 79},
  {2 => 46},
  {3 => 19},
  {4 => 8},
  {5 => 2},
  {6 => 1}
]
```

How do i write this in both pure Mongo, and in Mongoid?

Thank you in advance!

### EDIT

Found a pretty much a duplicate question:
[Use mongodb aggregation framework to group by length of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955072/use-mongodb-aggregation-framework-to-group-by-length-of-array)

And this post suggests exploiting a trick using unwind and group to count the length of the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use mongodb aggregation framework to group by length of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955072/use-mongodb-aggregation-framework-to-group-by-length-of-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development version 2.5.3 of MongoDB introduces the $size operator for the aggregation pipeline.  If you use that version, you could try:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: { $size: "$myArray" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } } ] )
```

As mentioned, the $size operator is currently available in version 2.5.3, which is for dev/testing purposes.

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Mongoid.

Hope this helps.

Kay

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait few days to see if anyone posts an answer for mongoid, or if I can figure it out.